# Solr text searching not working

Tags: solr

I am using solr.TextField instead of solr.DateField to store the date value.
Assume I have a record with "date" field value ="20/10/2014, 20/5/2015", I am trying to search "20/10/2014" in order to get this record. But it doesn't work.
My query is like: `q=*:*&fq=date:20/10/2014`
Please help how I can configure the field or the query in order to get the record.

```
<field name="date" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: I just try with query q=*:*&fq=Comments:pits/bumps, my Comments is also a text_general type like yours, It's actually work for me. I also noticed you q is just :, is that why you can not get a result?

Comment: Sorry, a typo there. I use debugQuery=true to check how it analyzes 20/10/2014. It simple split it into date=20 date=10 date=2014, that's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: please use a proper field type to store dates, as that will allow you to actually handle them in a suitable way, both concerning indexing, faceting, retrieving records within intervals, etc.

The whole issue stems from your field definitions, which isn't suitable for date handling at all. Using a TextField together with a StandardTokenizer will do weird stuff to content in the format you're supplying, and you'll have tokens that are too short to be usable for indexing. Applying LowerCasing and StopFiltering to dates isn't a good idea either.

If you really, really want to avoid using a proper type, and want to implement it as a TextField, you'll have to make it behave for the type of content you're indexing. It seems you have a list of dates separated by `,`, so you'll be better off by using a `PatternTokenizer` instead - splitting each date into a separate token and then doing nothing more with it.

[The example on the wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer) is made to parse this format (tokens separated by optional whitespace and `,`):

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*,\s*" />
```

Since the rest of the token is part of how you want to query the field, you don't want to apply any filters (and there's no need to provide the same sequence of tokenizers and filters for both indexing and querying if they're identical).